# Create hyperlink which links to cell with matching text in next sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to replace all the text present in column B of sheet1 with hyperlinks which would traverse to the sheet and cell which has the mentioned text (second occurrence).

Suppose we have sheet1:

```
Column A : Column B
T1       : Brand Values
T2       : Brand Text
```

Just like we can achieve through Find all option.

[image]

So for the above option, create a hyperlink to Sheet 2 cell reference A3.

I got the VBA code to create links:

```
ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= "'" & sh.Name & "'" & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=sh.Name
```

How do I find the cell reference for the matched text in another sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for each worksheet, find the match.

then write the matched address to Hyperlink.

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim mySht As Worksheet, sht As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range, myRng As Range

    Set mySht = ActiveSheet
    For Each cell In mySht.Range("B2:B3")
        For Each sht In Worksheets
            If sht.Name <> mySht.Name Then    ' find each worksheet except myself
                Set myRng = Nothing
                On Error Resume Next
                Set myRng = sht.Cells.Find(what:=cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)    ' find match
                If Not myRng Is Nothing Then
                    mySht.Hyperlinks.Add _
                        anchor:=cell, _
                        Address:="", _
                        SubAddress:=myRng.Address(True, True, xlA1, True), _
                        TextToDisplay:=cell.Value
                    Exit For
                End If
                On Error Goto 0
            End If
        Next sht
    Next cell
End Sub
```